# In text editor, switch statement shows enum value strange

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

My project is being developed into visual studio.
But suddenly, when I put a mouse over the switch statement, it looks like a picture.
Previously, numbers were displayed. How do we solve this?

[image: picture_1]

[image: picture_2]

Comment: Update your VS and make sure you aren't referencing any weird custom compiler packages? I'm more interested in why that entire line is green for you, is that your current debugger line? Cause that shouldn't be an executable line. Are you debugging with a different source file provided to VS?

Comment: Because the debugger is showing you different things. In the first case, it's a value, in the second case it's a switch label.

Comment: @Blindy It's not running, green background just shows what is selected in the IDE

Comment: The *`A`* `(label)` prefix, followed by the entire `case` statement is the clue...

Comment: @DavidG that's not the selection line because it has a caret inside. VS doesn't show the caret inside selections, it's always at the end.

Comment: @Blindy I ca show you an identical screenshot if you like?

Comment: @DavidG Go ahead. For reference, this is what a selection looks like: https://i.imgur.com/urYJGht.png -- caret at the end, always.

Comment: @Blindy Here you go... https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJcbm.gif

Comment: You have [the same tooltip as OP](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-84c97dd78a8e-gif-im/frame_007_delay-0.06s.gif), for me [it highlights the enum name and shows its value](https://i.imgur.com/sazjp7K.png), it doesn't highlight the entire case line. Also that isn't the selection, that's the little highlight thing Roslyn does.